# How to insert unmarshalled xml to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

Here is my struct to unmarshall xml:

```
type parseStruct struct {
First string `xml:"CharCode"`
Second string `xml:"Value"`
}


type xmlParse struct {
Data []parseStruct `xml:"Valute"`
}
```

Result:

```
{[{AA 30.2070000} {AB 29.9378} {AC 30.0260} {AD 30.3702}]}
```

How should i insert this construction to mongoDB?
I'm trying it
It is my mongo struct

```
type result struct{
    First string
    Second string
}
```

Here is insert operation

```
for i, _ := range unm.Data {
        collection.Insert(result{

            Curr1: unm.Data[i].First,
            Rate: unm.Data[i].Second,
        })
        fmt.Println("result", dataBatt.Data2[i].Rate, dataBatt.Data2[i].Curr1)
    }
```

But if i need put to add to mongodb base other unmarshalled structure, similar to it but from other structure for example:

```
type parseSecondStruct struct {
    First string `xml:"Char"`
    Second string `xml:"Val"`
    }

    type xmlParse struct {
    Data []parseSecondStruct `xml:"Valute"`
    }
```

How should i paste 2 unrmashalled result in result struct and know where is result from 1 source and where is from 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far? ;)

Comment: edited :) hope somebody will help me